# Overleaf and "review" (track changes)

Tags: overleaf

[image: review button]

The review button in the Overleaf editor lets you track changes in the source text, but sometimes you wish to show the changes that is done to other people than those who have access to the Overleaf editor (teachers, reviewers, etc..).

Are there any packages that make the comments appear in the PDF file?

/Lars

Comment: To my understanding, it shows you the changes in the text in a comment, but you don't see it in the compiled version of the pdf. If you want to see the changes in the pdf I'd recommend `changes` package

Comment: For questions about how Overleaf works, I'd recommend asking their support team directly through their contact form.

Comment: [Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.] At present, those comments and tracked-changes aren't captured in the output PDF indeed—sorry about this. And indeed if you have further questions, feel free to use the contact form as @skillmon mentioned, or email support@overleaf.com!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about TeX/LaTeX, as such.

Answer (score 2):

There's the changes package which was mentioned by @Elad Den but also latexdiff which seems like a good fix if you don't want to manually add code into the doc, as you can just make a copy of the original document and merge with the revised document.

changes: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/tracking-changes-in-latex-with-changes-package/fnpkpytjjwhj
latexdiff: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Using_Latexdiff_For_Marking_Changes_To_Tex_Documents